# .length для <input> выдаёт undefined

Tags: javascript

Код принимает из `<input>` число и должен его обработать по количеству символов:

```
var x = document.getElementById("short_number"); // пришло 6666
alert(x.value); // выдало 6666
alert(x.length); // выдало "undefined"
```

Почему `x.length` выдаёт `undefined`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не работает потому, что нет такого свойства у `HTMLElement`. Если вы хотите получить значение атрибута `length` тега `<input>`, то вам нужно использовать:

```
x.getAttribute('length');
```

А если длину строки, то:

```
x.value.length;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я так сразу и подумал, но начал писать и DreamWeaver после x.value. не стал предлагать варианты, и я не проверил. Положился на него, думал так перебор. А оказалось нет.
P.S. Не всегда надо полагаться лишь на IDE...

Comment: @I_CaR, полагаться только на IDE - это, как минимум, не профиссионально. Учите мат. часть ;)

Comment: Я с JS не сильно дружу. Больше PHP+MySQL.
Это я старый (8-летней давности) скрипт решил подправить.

Answer (score 2):

Разобрался!

```
a=x.value; // присвоим "а" значение от x.value, т.е. сюда идёт 6666
alert(a.length) // здесь получим 4
```